# Simple Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I would like to double check my work on these probability questions. The questions is below followed by my possible correct answers.

4 finalists are selected at random from a pool of 14 candidates. The search committee placed each candidate into one of the three separate categories. A: 5; B: 3; C: 6.

a) Describe the sample space. Find the probability that none of the finalists are from group B.

b) What is the probability that either category A or category B is not represented in the group of finalists?

c) Given that none of the finalists fall in group B, what is the probability that exactly 3 falls in category C?

**Answers**

a) Sample space is all possible combos of $14 choose 4=1001$. Probability that none are from group B is complement that they are all from group B. But B only has 3 candidates so left with 11 extra (sum from A and C). Hence for four slots if we fill first three from group B that leaves us with 11 choices for the last slot. Hence we have $11$ ways so far. But there are $4!$ ways to move the people around, hence we get $4!*11$. So probability here is $1-\frac{4!*11}{1001}=.736$

b) Prob of A or B is complement of A and B selected. Since must have at least one from each group have minimum of 1 and maximum of 3. Therefore we get,

$\frac{{5\choose3}{3\choose 1}}{1001}+\frac{{5\choose2}{3\choose 2}}{1001}+\frac{{5\choose1}{3\choose 3}}{1001}$.

But also four factorial ways to arrange. So we get $\frac{1506}{1001}$, which is incorrect. Maybe my arithmetic is incorrect here.

c) Here it is simply probability of exactly 3 from c divided by part a from above. So in order to get exactly 3 from group C is just $6 \choose3$ and then to get the last person from group a, is $5 choose1$. Then multiply by $4!$ to rearrange. But once again I get $2400/1001$. Clearly I am not conditioning things correctly.

Is my process right though, like is this the correct way of going about it, or is there a simpler method?

Comment: In (a), the probability of none being from group B is not the complement of the probability of all being from group B. Rather, it is the complement of the probability of at least one being from group B. Instead, you may consider approaching it directly - if none are from group B, how many candidates are available for each slot?

Answer (score 0):

In a), there's a minor error:
$$\newcommand{\c}[2]{^{#1}{\rm C}_{#2}}
\newcommand{\d}[1]{{\rm #1}}
\d P=\frac{\c{11}4}{\c{14}4}$$
You don't need $4!$.

In b), it's either that means "one of the two but not both". Also since they're 
$$\d P=\d P(\d A')+\d P(\d B')=\frac{\c94}{\c{14}4}+\frac{\c{11}4}{\c{14}4}$$
You don't need $4!$ here too.

In c), there's a minor error:
$$\d P=\frac{\c51\c63}{\c{14}4}$$
And... you don't need the $4!$ here too.

Comment: since they are independent?

Comment: @Jack since you need to "select" not "arrange". Also if your sample space was also arranged(i.e. *4!) then it would be fine.

Comment: why in part c do you subtract it from 1?

Comment: @Jack sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Complimentary probabilities can be a bit tricky so I'll point out where your thought process went off the rails. Remember, complimentary probability works because when you add P(A) and P(B) you get 1. So you have to think hard about both whether P(A) and P(B) represent all possibilities and whether they are mutually exclusive possibilities.

a) Probability of 'no candidates from B' is not complimentary to 'all candidates from B'. They are opposite situations in a way, but they do not describe all the possibilities. What happens if there are 2 candidates selected from group B? This does not fall into either category. Here are two examples which are complimentary.

P(All Candidates selected from B) + P(3 or less candidates selected from B) = 1

P(No Candidates selected from B) + P(1 or more candidates selected from B) = 1

Your calculation of the sample space of 1001 is correct. You can also directly calculate the probability of selecting no candidates from group B. If you can't choose people from group B, that means every person must come from either group A or C. This is a pool of 11 total people. Then it's just $\binom{11}{4}$.

b. Your complimentary probability is right, but your calculation is wrong. The compliment of either A or B not represented is that both A and B have at least one representative. This is a calculation I don't know how to do. Another way to calculate it is to add the probabilities of A happening to the probability of B happening minus the probability of A and B happening. 
$$ \binom{11}{4} + \binom{9}{4} - \binom{6}{4} = 441$$

c. Your thoughts are exactly right, just don't multiply.